# error deploying an API rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

i'm trying to deploy a simple rails app that access and retrieve data from the openweathermap API and display the info. Locally I could search and see the results, but after deploying to Heroku, I get an error everytime I try to retrieve data from the API. IN the logs, it says

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    2017-03-28T23:13:39.240642+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]     1:

Forecast for <%=@w["name"] %> , <%=@w["sys"]["country"] %>

etc..

But I really don't know where to fix it

```
2017-03-28T22:34:26.249586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-ee2ce37cbf576e743a25b85e1834b055fe1564a1a8b891ed64f7fd521f2f88dc.js" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=4954e1e4-8411-4365-b36f-87bddf0b5693 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2017-03-28T22:34:26.489479+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=b25b4025-5c8e-4e70-8008-ad3613062e57 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2017-03-28T22:34:30.360691+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/forecast/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=76.26&lon=78.5&commit=Search" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=48ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=https
2017-03-28T22:34:30.333448+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd] Started GET "/forecast/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=76.26&lon=78.5&commit=Search" for 83.138.193.223 at 2017-03-28 22:34:30 +0000
2017-03-28T22:34:30.336021+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd] Processing by ForecastController#show as HTML
2017-03-28T22:34:30.336091+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "lat"=>"76.26", "lon"=>"78.5", "commit"=>"Search"}
2017-03-28T22:34:30.377650+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41ms
2017-03-28T22:34:30.378635+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd]
2017-03-28T22:34:30.378666+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd] NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2017-03-28T22:34:30.378724+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd]
2017-03-28T22:34:30.378760+00:00 app[web.1]: [6148657c-8bdf-4ff0-b503-5b2f798c48bd] app/controllers/forecast_controller.rb:10:in `show'
2017-03-28T22:39:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2017-03-28T22:39:59.041896+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user 
2017-03-28T22:39:59.041896+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fb86924 by user 
2017-03-28T22:39:59.418597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-03-28T22:39:59.419192+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-03-28T22:39:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2017-03-28T22:39:59.349997+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user 
2017-03-28T22:40:00.214967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-03-28T22:40:00.229628+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2017-03-28 22:40:00 +0000 ===
2017-03-28T22:40:00.229632+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2017-03-28T22:40:00.229478+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2017-03-28T22:40:00.230195+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-28T22:40:00.540700+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-03-28T22:40:02.360668+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 55627 -e production`
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219721+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219741+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:55627
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219742+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219743+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219748+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Sassy Salamander
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219749+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219844+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:55627
2017-03-28T22:40:06.220162+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-03-28T22:40:06.219749+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-03-28T22:40:06.598858+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-28T22:40:42.536212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=612b3cbc-181e-469d-9aaa-873bbf9968f2 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=52ms status=200 bytes=1849 protocol=http
2017-03-28T22:40:42.467816+00:00 app[web.1]: [612b3cbc-181e-469d-9aaa-873bbf9968f2] Started GET "/" for 83.138.193.223 at 2017-03-28 22:40:42 +0000
2017-03-28T22:40:42.469755+00:00 app[web.1]: [612b3cbc-181e-469d-9aaa-873bbf9968f2] Processing by ForecastController#index as HTML
2017-03-28T22:40:42.510151+00:00 app[web.1]: [612b3cbc-181e-469d-9aaa-873bbf9968f2]   Rendering forecast/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-03-28T22:40:42.514148+00:00 app[web.1]: [612b3cbc-181e-469d-9aaa-873bbf9968f2]   Rendered forecast/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
2017-03-28T22:40:42.515750+00:00 app[web.1]: [612b3cbc-181e-469d-9aaa-873bbf9968f2] Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 6.8ms)
2017-03-28T22:40:43.593017+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=4a90a1ba-f4e4-4f7c-a943-87d4f1a3970e fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=195 protocol=http
2017-03-28T22:40:43.575325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-ee2ce37cbf576e743a25b85e1834b055fe1564a1a8b891ed64f7fd521f2f88dc.js" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=6135d581-15ab-473d-a87a-1596e7e03090 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=46469 protocol=http
2017-03-28T22:40:44.234523+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=be9a2e95-846e-4d30-851b-81bafa7e56f7 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=http
2017-03-28T22:40:47.756522+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/forecast/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=76.26&lon=78.5&commit=Search" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=45ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=http
2017-03-28T22:40:47.716158+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d] Started GET "/forecast/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=76.26&lon=78.5&commit=Search" for 83.138.193.223 at 2017-03-28 22:40:47 +0000
2017-03-28T22:40:47.717619+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d] Processing by ForecastController#show as HTML
2017-03-28T22:40:47.717714+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "lat"=>"76.26", "lon"=>"78.5", "commit"=>"Search"}
2017-03-28T22:40:47.757911+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms
2017-03-28T22:40:47.758737+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d]
2017-03-28T22:40:47.758792+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d] NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2017-03-28T22:40:47.758844+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d]
2017-03-28T22:40:47.758878+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9cbecd-7e71-4e94-a776-a29666ef6f9d] app/controllers/forecast_controller.rb:10:in `show'

2017-03-28T23:12:19.347563+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2017-03-28T23:12:19.348091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2017-03-28T23:12:20.005914+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-03-28T23:12:20.018999+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2017-03-28T23:12:20.019211+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2017-03-28 23:12:20 +0000 ===
2017-03-28T23:12:20.019217+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2017-03-28T23:12:20.019356+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-03-28T23:12:20.264562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-03-28T23:12:22.066287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 36303 -e production`
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311385+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311398+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:36303
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311399+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311400+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311404+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.2.6-p396), codename: Sassy Salamander
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311405+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311406+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311509+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:36303
2017-03-28T23:12:26.311880+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-03-28T23:12:26.769039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-03-28T23:13:33.521802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=455bb1ab-e6d2-4825-9628-c1553b31a785 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=53ms status=200 bytes=1849 protocol=http
2017-03-28T23:13:33.642413+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-d403d1f8080b3ad942ca24506e1f1740ea2e952a983bd838c871305f1d738e17.js" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=073f6766-124f-4294-8906-bec4e53e6866 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=46527 protocol=http
2017-03-28T23:13:33.654785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-38d14876a278d516415b9f33c99616f2f16aee4b8f502e55085ad10a5781bbdd.css" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=41a6d3e5-2b4c-4ce4-8fcf-c821a2c0f00f fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=217 protocol=http
2017-03-28T23:13:33.449653+00:00 app[web.1]: [455bb1ab-e6d2-4825-9628-c1553b31a785] Started GET "/" for 83.138.193.223 at 2017-03-28 23:13:33 +0000
2017-03-28T23:13:33.454539+00:00 app[web.1]: [455bb1ab-e6d2-4825-9628-c1553b31a785] Processing by ForecastController#index as HTML
2017-03-28T23:13:33.487661+00:00 app[web.1]: [455bb1ab-e6d2-4825-9628-c1553b31a785]   Rendering forecast/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-03-28T23:13:33.494523+00:00 app[web.1]: [455bb1ab-e6d2-4825-9628-c1553b31a785]   Rendered forecast/index.html.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
2017-03-28T23:13:33.496670+00:00 app[web.1]: [455bb1ab-e6d2-4825-9628-c1553b31a785] Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 10.8ms)
2017-03-28T23:13:34.546011+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=51712a1f-3d81-4a80-bc1a-3d8ea6415c30 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=http
2017-03-28T23:13:39.242712+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/forecast/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=76.26&lon=78.5&commit=Search" host=frozen-river-81321.herokuapp.com request_id=9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42 fwd="83.138.193.223" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=53ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=http
2017-03-28T23:13:39.198411+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42] Processing by ForecastController#show as HTML
2017-03-28T23:13:39.197228+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42] Started GET "/forecast/show?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=76.26&lon=78.5&commit=Search" for 83.138.193.223 at 2017-03-28 23:13:39 +0000
2017-03-28T23:13:39.198518+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "lat"=>"76.26", "lon"=>"78.5", "commit"=>"Search"}
2017-03-28T23:13:39.236523+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]   Rendering forecast/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-03-28T23:13:39.238896+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 40ms
2017-03-28T23:13:39.238659+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]   Rendered forecast/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240291+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240332+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42] ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240642+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]     1: <h1>Forecast for <%=@w["name"] %> , <%=@w["sys"]["country"] %></h1>
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240643+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]     2: <p>Find me in app/views/forecast/show.html.erb</p>
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240645+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]     4: <div class="result">
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240644+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]     3: <% if !@w.nil?  %>
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240671+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42]
2017-03-28T23:13:39.240709+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42] app/views/forecast/show.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_forecast_show_html_erb__4480134760202078404_70214950094520
```

Comment: have you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: @TomaszBubała yes i have run it. Still get the same error "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Answer (score 0):

Your log said:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass): 2017-03-28T23:13:39.240642+00:00 app[web.1]: [9630d05d-78ea-4e76-9c22-17a05ce56b42] 1:

Forecast for <%=@w["name"] %> , <%=@w["sys"]["country"] %>
```

Look like your variable `@w` or `@w["sys"]` is `nil`. I think you should check it.

```
Forecast for <%=@w["name"] if @w.present? %> , <%=@w["sys"]["country"] if @w.present? && if @w["sys"].present? %>
```

Hope I can help!